# LongListSelector grouping GlobeGroupKey

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, grouping, longlistselector

I'm using a slight variation of the `AlphaKeyGroup` class included in the `toolkit`, for grouping in my `LongListSelector`. Everything works fine, except the `GlobeGroupKey`. While on the emulator, the key is displayed as it should (like the one on the people app) when deployed to my device it looks a bit different. Notice the White Background and the PhoneAccentBrush colored curves of the globe key in the device snapshot.

***Emulator***

[image]

***Device***

[image]

I'm declaring the Key for the group as it is in the AlphaKeyGroup:

```
private const string GlobeGroupKey = "\uD83C\uDF10";
```

Anyone knows whats going on and how it can be fixed?

Comment: I've noticed that in the facebook app which is an official microsoft app a longlistselector that displays your friends list behaves in the same manner. If microsoft can't sort it I guess I'm hopeless :P